# How to get currently signed-in user with GoogleSignInApi?

Tags: android, google-signin

I see [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/people) that you can get the user's account after the sign-in intent succeeds, by this:

```
Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data).getSignInAccount();
```

`data` is the data you receive in `onActivityResult()`.

Is there say a static method in the API that can give me the account as a `GoogleSignInResult` or `GoogleSignInAccount` object that I can use later on in my code, not necessarily when I get an ActivityResult?

For example in Facebook the equivelant of what I want is:

```
Profile.getCurrentProfile();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the current user easily like this.

```
OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (opr.isDone()) {
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = opr.get().getSignInAccount();
        // use acct to get all the information you want abt the user
    }
```

Comment: How do you get the `mGoogleApiClient`?

Comment: mGoogleApiClient is the GoogleApiClient object you should be having since it links you to your Google App. Look at the docs on how to build this object (usually at the start of the activity).  https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client